# websocket conection problem in the console establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, console, google-chrome-devtools, npx

anyone knows which it's this error when I develop an `create-react-app` and run the console?

`reload.js:22 WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:5500/ws' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

the app it's still in his start form, nothing changed.

I don't know if it is a problem of my computer/browser or something else? I checked and the problem didn't show up in `firefox`

Comment: Very hard to say without additional information. Note, by default react-start would start a development http server at localhost:3000 which is http://127.0.0.1:3000.

Comment: and what type of info I can add?

Comment: 1. Why are you using a raw websocket instead of the default http dev server that create-react-app provides?
2. The changes you made to package.json to do that.
3. Operating system, user permission (raw ports wouldn't work without sudo)
4. ufw changes you made to allow raw ports.

Comment: I didn't change anything, and now I checked and I have the same error when I open the console here in stackoverflow, maybe it's a problem of chrome?

Comment: I checked and the problem doesn't show up in firefox, so it's a problem of chrome